# MongoDB Query C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

I am having trouble with expressing this query in C# MongoDB, I want it to return all the results of an `objectID` where it does not equal to `"000000000000000000000000"` which works in MongoVue; But I can't get it work in my program.

```
{"ProfilePictureId" : {$ne: new ObjectId ("000000000000000000000000")}}
```

I am using official C# driver:

```
var query = new QueryDocument();
foreach (BsonDocument book in col.Find(query))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can build your query as follows:

```
var query = Query.NE("ProfilePictureId", ObjectId.Empty);
```

`ObjectId.Empty` returns an `ObjectId` composed of all zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are querying for documents of a class looking something like:

```
public class Profile {
        public ObjectId ProfilePictureId { get; set; }
        //... other attributes, construcotrs, methods etc...
}
```

You can also write your query using expression lambdas like this:

```
var query = Query<Profile>.NE(s => s.ProfilePictureId, ObjectId.Empty);
```